# Java - Update object fields with matching fields of POJO

Tags: java

Newer Java user, finding myself doing something I'd like to do cleaner.

Suppose I have a class that get's updated through a call `update(final Parameters params)`:

```
@Data // using lombok
class Updatable {
    public int x = 0;
    public String a = 'hello'
   
    // some ctors/methods

    public void update(final Parameters params) {
        x = params.getX();
        a = params.getA();
    }
}
```

Where there `Parameters`  POJO is simply:

```
@Value
class Parameters {
    int x;
    String a;
}
```

So the fields of the POJO will always (by convention, not contract). Is there a way to avoid calling the getter for each field an simply map the fields of the POJO to the corresponding fields of the class being updated?

Comment: With `ModelMapper` perhaps? https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper

Comment: @slindenau yes this would work, however the package is not a part of our dependency chain and I would like to avoid adding any in for something like this. Is there a native Java way or a Lomok-ism to support this?

Comment: Perhaps, but i don't know about it. Perhaps with a bit of manual work you could match properties with this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html